# Join against query using Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to run a query like this using sequelize but I'm not sure if it's possible:

```
select *
from t1
inner join (select * from table2 order by field1 desc limit 1) t2
on t1.f1 = t2.f1
```

So I want to join `t1` against a single record from `t2`. Can this be done using the models?

Comment: you might need to use `literal` for the sub query.  https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/sub-queries/#using-sub-queries-for-complex-ordering

Comment: I attempted to do that but wan't sure how to combine with the sequelize `include` property.

Comment: I see. my bad.  looks like it is not supported yet https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11715#issuecomment-1023343174.
you might need raw `.query`